# mysql insert with fgetcsv - Turkish characters issue in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, fgetcsv

Im having problem while inserting CSV file to MySQL table

```
Collation = latin5_turkish_ci (also tried utf8_general_ci)
```

Im sure  the csv file UTF-8 (checked from Notepad++) tried both with BOM and without BOM also i tried `setlocale` 
Here is my code

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

// get the csv file
$file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
$handle = fopen($file,"r");

// loop through the csv file and insert into database
do {
    if ($data[0]) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact (contact_first, contact_last) VALUES
            (
                '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                '".addslashes($data[1])."'
            )
        ");
    }
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

The Output is

```
kelbaÅ? hÃ¼seyin
```

What i need

```
kelbaş hüseyin
```

Thanks for answers

Comment: Solved: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/